# Converting a currency string into a float number issue

Tags: ios, localization, nsstring, locale

Say my current locale is Canada, When I try to convert a 10,000.00 using:

```
    float num = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10,000.00" locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]].floatValue;
```

num will become 10.00.

Is there something wrong or is this an iOS bug? or the "," is not what it expects as the apostrophe?

Comment: also, 12,345.67 gives me 12.345000

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"100.1"];
NSLog(@"%@", [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:number numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]);
```

Comment: try putting 10,000.1, it gives 10